# How to initialize std::chrono::miliseconds in an empty constructor?

Tags: c++, c++-chrono, default-constructor

I have default constructor for object which contains std::chrono::miliseconds (using =default does not work - compiler deletes it). I cannot do it other way like initializing it in constructor body, becouse other errors (not everything is initialized or missing initaializer) shows up.

```
object() : durationVal(???)
{
    //things
}
```

How do I initialize durationVal? (std::chrono::duration<long long, std::mili>)

Comment: [`durationVal(std::chrono::milliseconds(10))`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration#Example) ?

Answer (score 0):

Mistake was that I had it as reference in the object and did not know about it.

```
std::chrono::duration<long long, std::mili>& durationVal;
```

instead of

```
std::chrono::duration<long long, std::mili> durationVal;
```

Comment: Why not `std::chrono::milliseconds durationVal;`?

Comment: I wrote it while I was learnig chrono library (2 days ago?). The code is a mess. I need to unify it.

Comment: Fair enough.  Perhaps this might help:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M